# Using variadic template as parameter for both class and method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

My question is about the following piece of code:

```
    template <class...T>
    class A
    {
    public:
        template <class...S>
        static void a() { }
    };

    template <class...T>
    class B
    {
    public:
        template <class...S>
        void b()
        {
            A<T...>::a<S...>();
        }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

I have a class `A` that has a variadic template and contains a static method `a` that has another variadic template. From somewhere else (class `B` in this case) I have two different sets of variadic templates I want to pass to `A::a`.

The compiler (GCC 4.8.1) gives the following error message:

```
    main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void B<T>::b()’:
    main.cpp:16:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
             A <T...>::a<S...>();
                          ^
    main.cpp:16:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
```

Also notice that when I change the method `b()` to this:

```
        void b()
        {
            A<int, char, short>::a<S...>();
        }
```

or some other specification of A's templates then the code compiles just fine.

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Note that things get particularly funky when you expand boths packs in one expression: they get expanded in lockstep

Comment: @sehe this is two separate pack expansions, not a single pattern expanding two packs simultaneously (e.g., `f(A<T>::a<S>()...)`). So the expansions are independent.

Comment: @Casey I know, right. This is why it's a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add template here

```
A<T...>::template a<S...>();
```

see comment for reason. Also this compile nicely on VC++ without the keyword so I guess it is compiler dependent.

Comment: VC++ doesn't implement two-phase name lookup in templates; it effectively treats every name as a dependent name.

Comment: Or to be more clear: MSVC violates the standard by not requiring `template` there.  It should treat `A<T...>::a` as a value, then treat `<` as less than, then have a parsing error when you put `S...` on the right-hand-side of a `<` expression.  The idea is that errors can be found in `template` prior to instantiating them: MSVC fails to find entire categories of errors, so it doesn't need the `template` disambiguator.